# How to dispatch a set of Vuex actions synchronously (wait for a set to settle, and then dispatch another)

Tags: javascript, async-await, vuex

I have a couple of Vuex actions that return axios Promises.
I want to run action X a few times, and after those actions end, I want to run action Y a few times, here's what I've tried:

```
async save() {
  const ingredients = [{ 1 }, { 2 }]
  const ingredients_actions = ingredients.map(async ing => await this.$store.dispatch('saveIngredients', ing))
  const recipes = [{ a }, { b }, { c }]
  const recipes_actions = recipes.map(async recipe => await this.$store.dispatch('saveRecipe', recipe)

  await Promise.all(ingredients_actions)
  await Promise.all(recipes_actions)
}
```

In the network tab in the console I expect to see the ingredients_actions calls happen, and then see the recipes_actions happen. Instead I'm seeing the actions happen all over the place, not synchronously at all.

How to make all the ingredients_actions happen before the recipes_actions? All suggestions welcome.

Comment: you can directly use await ingredients_actions and then await recipes_actions. you don't need Promise.all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what is expected ?

```js
async save() {
  const ingredients = [{ 1 }, { 2 }]
  const ingredients_actions = ingredients.map(async ing => await this.$store.dispatch('saveIngredients', ing))
  await Promise.all(ingredients_actions)

  const recipes = [{ a }, { b }, { c }]
  const recipes_actions = recipes.map(async recipe => await this.$store.dispatch('saveRecipe', recipe)
  await Promise.all(recipes_actions)
}
```

Comment: it's getting there, but what I'm seeing now is the order of the operations getting reversed sometimes. I'll keep testing it

Answer (score 1):

you have to immediately wrap your map with `Promise.all()` as your iteration function are uncontrolled (errors won't be handled). 
the other approach is to use `<Function>.bind()`.

this might work for you:

```
async save() {
  const ingredients = [{ 1 }, { 2 }];
  const recipes = [{ a }, { b }, { c }]

  await Promise.all(ingredients.map(ingredient => this.$store.dispatch('saveIngredients', ingredient)));
  await Promise.all(recipes.map(recipe => this.$store.dispatch('saveRecipe', recipe)));
}
```